# no bundle for BundleID: (null) Game Center

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

Because when I try to send a medal completed Game Center I get the error:

> no bundle for BundleID: (null)

The code I use is:

```
GKAchievement.reportAchievements ([achievement], ...
```

The medal is not completed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Achiviement Game Center iOS Swift 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39064088/achiviement-game-center-ios-swift-2)

Comment: Not a duplicate: here we look for a strange warning in Xcode. The other one is asking to read the chapter "testing" in the GameCenter Guide for him.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happens in the current version of the simulator only. I get it too, but the code works fine with achievements shown in GameCenter and on a real device (iPhone 6) this line does not show up.

Comment: To me it also appears on the device launched by Xcode. I have not tried it on TestFlight. But it is normal that I can not even see the medal to complete it by the device?

Comment: It might take a while to see your reports on GameCenter.  Depending on how busy GameCenter is in the band with of your network. Usually five minutes later, all reports should be reflected there.